# How to prevent people from ever using the Founder Titan again without rendering it inoperable?

Tags: science-based, robots, security

So, If you're familiar with the anime GATE (not to be confused with Stein's Gate) or *A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court*, you probably know what's going on and why I have a boiling hatred towards earthlings

One day, in the middle of your fantasy world, a gate opens up to another world, i.e: modern-day Earth. Sure things might seem okay, since when would you be stupid enough to try and fight a completely unknown enemy, but as time goes forward the lustrous green pastures get replaced with cities and there will always be at least one ruin pub next to an ancient site. Also, if dragons complain about their favorite rivers tasting like detergent, well, that's their problem. *"Move somewhere else."*

I decided to nip this trouble in the bud with a 15-meter tall giant, The Founder Titan.

### Founder Titan

The Founder Titan is a 15-meter tall, biomimetic android with a human pilot, located in the nape. While its body is made up of the toughest materials known (graphene-reinforced stuff, etc..), this thing's true power comes from the billions of tiny robots that swirl around it, creating a fog 1.5-2 kilometers in radius. These robots are called foglets, their swarm, the utility fog.

> Hall thought of it as a nanotechnological replacement for car
>   seatbelts. The robots would be microscopic, with extending arms
>   reaching in several different directions and could perform
>   three-dimensional lattice reconfiguration. Grabbers at the ends of the
>   arms would allow the robots (or foglets) to mechanically link to one
>   another and share both information and energy, enabling them to act as
>   a continuous substance with mechanical and optical properties that
>   could be varied over a wide range. Each foglet would have substantial
>   computing power, and would be able to communicate with its neighbors.
>
> In the original application as a replacement for seatbelts, the swarm
>   of robots would be widely spread out, and the arms loose, allowing air
>   flow between them. In the event of a collision the arms would lock
>   into their current position, as if the air around the passengers had
>   abruptly frozen solid. The result would be to spread any impact over
>   the entire surface of the passenger's body.
>
> While the foglets would be micro-scale, construction of the foglets
>   would require full molecular nanotechnology. Hall suggests that each
>   bot may be in the shape of a dodecahedron with twelve arms extending
>   outwards. Each arm would have four degrees of freedom. **The foglets'
>   bodies would be made of aluminum oxide rather than combustible diamond
>   to avoid creating a fuel air explosive.**

-Wikiped

As you guessed, the Founder Titan can choose to create this smart air-fuel explosive that can be dispersed and condensed at will.

---

So, in the epic battle against the entire US Army, the Founder Titan simply goes to a nearby hiding spot, disperses the fog and recondenses it at the base around the gate, a small spark, and (on the other side of the gate)...

### [BOOOOM!](https://youtu.be/HJujtEBIQ14?t=57)

So, no more army, no more gate. Good, for us. There is still one problem, however.

The Founder Titan is incomprehensibly strong, compared to the rest of the world. Dragons are considered to be one of the most fearsome creatures because they can destroy a <s>village</s> hamlet in one go and kill one-two dozen soldiers. The Founder Titan looks at that, laughs, then blows up King's Landing, with Cersei, her pirate boyfriend, the war elephants, and the Molten Company still inside.

It's not like you can make another Founder Titan, as the methods of doing that were buried by its creators who themselves had vanished, 2000 years ago. To sum up:

- You can't destroy it
- You can't match it
- You most likely can't resist the temptation to use it
- You'll probably do everything in your power to use it again

This applies to the human pilot as well.

**The Founder will likely have to be used again, but until then, it somehow has to be on standby, but remain inaccessible to everyone (pilot included) and resist any attempt at cracking/jailbreaking without harming the cracker/jailbreaker. How can it do that?**

The people who are trying to crack it are equivalent to Earth's best experts.

Comment: Isekai crossed with Attack on Titan, except apparently everything has been built by Aperture Science. Given that, have you considered recruiting nothing but angsty teenagers against their will for pilots? That usually works for mecha anime.

Comment: @Halfthawed Asuka would still probably want to blow stuff up then for attention. Plus, they had MP EVAs, so just no. But, you mostly nailed the references **clap clap**.

Comment: The utility fog is obviously a consumable. If that's its best weapon, is there a need to lock it down? It's all used up.

Comment: maybe it need to cool down from overheat or over energy or over stress ? hence inaccessible until it calm down ?

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer:

The titan isn't self-powered.  It's powered by the existence of the gate itself, from the flux of the tear in reality (akin to the ZPMs from Stargate).  Once the gate closes, it only has enough power left to walk a few miles and lock itself down (hopefully after letting the pilot out).  This prevents its use except for when the gate has been opened.  Aside from that, your biggest challenge is going to be ensuring that the pilot acts in a manner you choose (they may, after all, decide that the modern cities look like a pretty nice place to live).

Why is it like that?  And why can't more of them be made, anyways?  The reason, lost to the mists of history, is that the titan isn't actually from your world, but from another.  None of the materials used are available here, and none of the knowledge ever was.  Perhaps the machine was piloted by a defector from an invading army.  Or perhaps an invading warlord's personal machine was stolen after spending a night amongst the locals.  Either way, it's here now.

Comment: That wouldn't work out because the Founder was built thousands of years before, plus it's on standby, so the systems didn't completely shut down.

Comment: ..... As near as I know, my answer doesn't preclude any of those things?  What does it need to _do_ while on standby?

Comment: Knowing my electronic stuff, constant self-repair.

Comment: So low power state?  Not enough energy to walk around/fire weapons, but maintenance is autonomic.  That is, it's hibernating.

Comment: Sigh. It has to store energy somewhere, and standby should mean that it activates when needed. If it trickle-charges itself, that's bad design, if it doesn't that's worse. If energy is not the problem, then you have to lock the software and hardware somehow.

Comment: ... I said it was powered by the existence of the gate, which means energy is the problem.  Do you need it to activate other than when the gate is open?

Comment: It's getting into story territory, yes. The gate was merely one of many curses, spells of unknown origin that can affect entire continents and always require a condition to be met. Only one thing is scary enough to deal with them...

Answer (score 0):

**Founder Titan is inaccessible.**

Stow it in one of the regular inaccessible places.  Seabed.  Volcano, under lava.  Orbit.  Or maybe back thru that gate and then thru another and another and then thru a weird one, and leave it there.

You cant crack it if you cant get to it.